# Different versions of Schwinger parameterization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, metric-tensor, conventions, propagator, wick-rotation

One common used trick when calculating loop integral is [Schwinger parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization). And I have seen two versions among wiki, arxiv and lecture notes.
$$\frac{1}{A}=\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \ e^{-tA}$$
or,
$$\frac{-i}{(-i)A}=-i\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \ e^{itA}$$
where $A=p^2-m^2+i\epsilon$.

I know the latter is surely true since its real part $Re(-iA)=\epsilon\gt0$ and thus applicable for the equation
$$\frac{1}{a}=\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t \ e^{-at}\ \text{   for   } Re(a)\gt0.$$
But as for the former, it doesn't hold true for space-like which the loop momentum probably behaves like , i.e. $p^2-m^2\lt0$. I am very confused why so many people still use the first one and any explanation will be appreciated!

Comment: Which wiki, arXiv and lecture notes? Which page?

Comment: Part of them are :1. https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~shapiro/615/lects/schwingertrick.pdf at page 1;  2. http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/~kleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/08.pdf at page106;  3. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0604068 at page11

Comment: In fact, I feel like that many people have used the first identity during their deduction in practice like hadronic loop calculation without any explicit explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Schwinger parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_parametrization) itself is manifestly positive. In particular, it is not Wick-rotated, so there are not different versions of it. Rather it is OP's $A$ operator that is Wick-rotated.

OP lists a few references in above comments.

- Ref. 1 works in Euclidean signature, so it's well-defined.
- Ref. 2 & 3 only use the Schwinger parameter to derive the [Feynman parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization). They, on the other hand, want to work in Minkowskian signature. In practice one would then have to argue (presumably case by case) if one can [analytically continue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)/[Wick-rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) from Euclidean signature to Minkowskian signature (thereby introducing the Feynman $i\epsilon$-prescription).

References:

1. H. Kleinert & V. Schulte-Frohlinde, *Critical Properties of $\phi^4$-Theories;* [chapter 8](http://users.physik.fu-berlin.de/%7Ekleinert/kleiner_reb8/psfiles/08.pdf), p. 106.
2. J.A. Shapiro, [*Schwinger trick and Feynman Parameters*](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/%7Eshapiro/615/lects/schwingertrick.pdf), 2007 lecture notes; p. 1.
3. S. Weinzierl, *The Art of Computing Loop Integrals,* [arXiv:hep-ph/0604068](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0604068); p. 11.

Comment: I really appreciate your explanation. I also realized that many people use the first identify based on the fact that most of loop integral can be wick-rotated and thus becomes well-defined, which hardly makes sense just mathematically.

Comment: One last question(maybe not really related) is how about the calculation of loop integral with complicated masses. The schwinger trick works as the real part stays the same. But I have no idea of the following steps of full calculation of loop integral like one-loop three-point. I don't know how to get the [Veltmen's deduction](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(79)90605-9) through schwinger parameterization. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi colin. Thanks for the feedback. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah. After schwinger parameterization, the one-loop three-point loop function becomes $\int d^3\vec{\alpha}\int \frac{d^4k}{i\pi^2}e^{-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3)k^2-2(\alpha_2p_1+\alpha_3p_2)k+\cdots}$. And I have no idea with the subsequent calculation either analytically or numerically especially when the masses are complex,i.e.$m_i=M_i-i\Gamma_i$

Comment: It matters because I usually deal with non-trivial numerator like $e^{\frac{k^2-m^2}{\Lambda^2}}$ and thus the loop integral becomes  $\int d^3\vec{\alpha}\int \frac{d^4k}{i\pi^2}e^{-(-1/\Lambda^2+\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3)k^2-2(\alpha_2p_1+\alpha_3p_2)k+\cdots}$ .This becomes hard for me